# Why round(4.5) == 4 and round(5.5) == 6 in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Looks like both 4.5 and 5.5 have exact float representations in Python 3.5:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(4.5)
Decimal('4.5')
>>> Decimal(5.5)
Decimal('5.5')
```

If this is the case, then why

```
>>> round(4.5)
4
>>> round(5.5)
6
```

?

Comment: Banker's rounding. You round to the nearest even number

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Python 3, exact half way numbers are rounded to the nearest even result. This [behavior changed in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)

> The [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function rounding strategy and return type have changed. Exact halfway cases are now rounded to the nearest even result instead of away from zero. (For example, round(2.5) now returns 2 rather than 3.) round(x[, n]) now delegates to x.**round**([n]) instead of always returning a float. It generally returns an integer when called with a single argument and a value of the same type as x when called with two arguments.

Comment: I think this can be solved using str with the round function, str(round(value))

Answer (score 5):

Python 3 uses Bankers Rounding, which rounds `.5` values to the closest even number.